# Rufus setting of "Standard Windows installation"

Tags: linux, windows, boot, rufus

The Rufus USB bootable flasher, there is a setting of "Standard Windows Installation" when flashing a Windows OS, as red highlighted in attached image below:

[image]

What does it actually do to the USB drive's boot record? I gather that it enters the keys that are digitally signed to be accepted among the UEFI's database.

If so, how do I force Rufus to enter the same keys to say, a Linux boot?

Answer (score 2):

Rufus only creates the boot media from the given ISO, it does not add
anything beyond what is already included in the ISO.

There are two options, which are "Standard Windows Installation" or
"Windows To Go" (Windows on a stick).
The second option was deprecated by Microsoft,
but Rufus might still be able to create it.
It is not necessary for Linux, because most Linux boot media is already
"To Go".